# Add queues and locks

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, locks

Hello I started to work on this code, the code is about a problem with traffic lights. One that will let the cars go to the right the other one that will let them go down/straight. The problem is that I would like to add queues but also some locks to make sure everything works correctly.

```
from re import T
import threading
import random
import time
import concurrent.futures
import traceback

x_squares = 5
y_squares = 5
coordinate_dictionary = {}
for x in range(0,x_squares + 1):
    for y in range(0,y_squares + 1):
        coordinate_dictionary[(x,y)] = {
        "right_queue": [],
        "down_queue": [],
        "where_to_go": "right" if x % 3 == 0 else "down",
        "right_queue_lock": threading.Lock(),
        "down_queue_lock": threading.Lock(),
        "x": x,
        "y": y
    }



def semaphore(structure):
        while is_the_program_over == False:
            print(f"The semaphor x: {structure['x']} y: {structure['y']} changing colors ")
            if structure["where_to_go"] == "right":
                structure["where_to_go"] = "down"
            else:
                structure["where_to_go"] = "right"
            time.sleep(random.randrange(3,7))


def cars(id):
        x,y = 0,0
        route = ""
        direction = random.randrange(1,3)
        if direction == 1:
            route = "down"
        else:
            route = "right"
        print(f"Car {id} is going on route: {route}")
        while x <= x_squares and y <= y_squares:
            print(f"Car {id} is moving from {x},{y}")
            if route == "down":
                dictionary = coordinate_dictionary[(x,y)]
                while dictionary["where_to_go"] != "down":
                    time.sleep(1)
                y = y+1
            if route == "right":
                dictionary = coordinate_dictionary[(x,y)]
                while dictionary["where_to_go"] != "right":
                    time.sleep(1)
                x = x+1
            print(f"Car {id} arrived to {x},{y}")
            time.sleep(1.5)


is_the_program_over = False
amount_of_cars = 25
amount_of_semaphors = len(coordinate_dictionary.items())

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=amount_of_semaphors) as executor:
    executor.map(semaphore, coordinate_dictionary.values())
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=amount_of_cars) as executor:
        executor.map(cars, range(amount_of_cars))
    is_the_program_over = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `threading.Condition` to handle queuing up your cars at each stoplight. One condition variable per stoplight should be enough, we don't actually need one for each direction, or a queue.

```
# setup code
for x in range(0,x_squares + 1):
    for y in range(0,y_squares + 1):
        coordinate_dictionary[(x,y)] = {
        "where_to_go": "right" if x % 3 == 0 else "down",
        "cv": threading.Condition(),
        "x": x,
        "y": y
    }

# logic for the stoplight
def semaphore(structure):
    condition = structure["cv"]
    while is_the_program_over == False:
        print(f"The semaphor x: {structure['x']} y: {structure['y']} changing colors ")
        with condition:                               # acquire the lock
            if structure["where_to_go"] == "right":   # change the direction
                structure["where_to_go"] = "down"
            else:
                structure["where_to_go"] = "right"
            condition.notify_all()                    # wake up any waiting cars
        time.sleep(random.randrange(3,7))

# logic for the cars
def cars(id):
    x,y = 0,0
    route = ""
    direction = random.randrange(1,3)
    if direction == 1:
        route = "down"
    else:
        route = "right"
    print(f"Car {id} is going on route: {route}")
    while x <= x_squares and y <= y_squares:
        print(f"Car {id} is moving from {x},{y}")
        if route == "down":
            dictionary = coordinate_dictionary[(x,y)]
            cv = dictionary["cv"]
            with cv:                                                     # acquire lock
                cv.wait_for(lambda: dictionary["where_to_go"] == "down") # wait if needed
            y = y+1
        if route == "right":
            dictionary = coordinate_dictionary[(x,y)]
            
            cv = dictionary["cv"]
            with cv:                                                     # same here
                cv.wait_for(lambda: dictionary["where_to_go"] == "right") 
            x = x+1
        print(f"Car {id} arrived to {x},{y}")
        time.sleep(1.5)
```